Jenkins processing log during pipeline fails
Running a C# script gives different results when in cmd vs Jenkins pipeline.
I'm running a Jenkins pipeline and in the post step I want to get the pipeline log from the server, split it into different files (one per stage) and upload it to some shared drive. This is all done via a C# script, here is the snippet of code that gives me the error:
if (File.Exists(logPath))
 {
     // copies the log file to current directory to avoid "file in use" error
     string destPath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "/log.txt";
     File.Copy(logPath, destPath, true);
     m_priv_logPath = destPath;
 }
 else
 {
     throw new Exception("File \"" + logPath + "\" does not exist");
 }

Running the same script with the exact same parameters from command line runs normally, but in Jenkins it goes in the else block, because File.Exists returns a false.
The log path is always a network path, so something like \\<machine-name>\<job-name>\jobs\builds\<build-number>\log
I'm not sure how I can debug this or what could be causing it. Any ideas?

Your Jenkins instance probably runs under a different user than you. And that user might not have the same permissions to access the network path in question. Add this command to your pipeline to see if Jenkins can access the file:
bat '\\\\<machine-name>\\<job-name>\\jobs\\builds\\<build-number>\\log'

Notice that I doubled \ because Groovy.

Indeed when I run that I get this error: The system cannot contact a domain controller to service the authentication request. Please try again later.

but Jenkins is logged in on the server as the same user I am logged in as, the machines are connected to the server via ssh, using the same account as well

In the end this was solved by some sysadmin meddling, we did two things so I'm not sure exactly which one was the actual fix:
update user credetials in Jenkins service
added more access for system user (most likely this was it)

What level of access did you provide to the account?

not sure as I wasn't the one to do it, but I'm assuming the highest level, since it was the system user
